# Storing data on browser

Tags: database, local-storage

I am on the process of modifying a database driven web application where a user may have multiple sub-accounts assigned to employees, these accounts only have access to certain areas of the main account.

The modification I am looking for is to have the application be accessible even when there is no internet or the connection is dropped.

All the users always have internet (cable or ADSL), the application is intended to run on a desktop; However there are cases where the internet connection drops and I need to store the transactions made by the employees so when the network comes back the data is sent to the server.

I been looking at solutions and seem to be stuck with local storage and a 5mb limit, I guess 5 mb will be ok if the internet fails for an hour or so but what if there is a longer wait?

Then my other issue is that the employees usually have access to only 1 or 2 computers max and they have to log-in and out constantly sharing the computer so how do I store those users credentials to allow them log in when there is no way for me to communicate with the server and validate?

Does anyone have any thoughts on what maybe my options?

Comment: In terms of more space, you may want to look into Indexeddb. You could, in theory, also store a copy of your user table in that db, and reimplement user auth against that. It cannot be secure, as the user is always able to manipulate that local data as they see fit through the console, but you could at least store the credentials they authed with to reauth when they can hit the server again. It does sound like you're pushing the edge of what "webapps" are supposed to be able to do.

Comment: @DylanWatt I guess what I could also do is store the transactions without real authentication  as you mention with Indexeddb then when the network is back send them along with the username/password that they entered and if it fails notify an admin so they can verify the transaction and attempt the login again, in any case the amount of employees per location is not that big, maybe 10 max, I been also thinking on just setting up a small web server on one of the computers at the location and store on mysql that way the passwords will be sort of safe

Comment: That could work, keep in mind if you store the password in plaintext, anyone with access to the browser could see other stored plaintext credentials.

Comment: @DylanWatt well no, for sure I wouldn't not store the passwords in plain text.

Comment: However, whatever you're storing is what gets sent to the server, and thus effectively the password. One could see another's stored credentials, hashed or otherwise, and then replicate those credentials in their own entry. Certainly it seems like a stretch that someone would do that, but I can't think of a way to make it wholly secured when whatever you store and the code it's stored with is accessible to anyone who opens the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the web server route.

I will set-up the server with the bare minimum data and logic.

Also decided to process all transactions through it which will also make the whole application faster, then the communication with the internet server can take its time without disrupting local processes.

There is also a monitor that works with a nodejs server which I will be moving locally so I can spare some server resources.

I guess this turned out to be a much better solution.

And about @DylanWatt password concern, I will have a different hash key for local database and remote database if the network is down the transaction stays only local once the network is back up I will wait for the user to re enter the password and then send those transactions on their way to the remote server along with the entered password.